# Gradle error version 1.2.3

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Version 1.2.3 of the Android Gradle plug-in requires Gradle 2.2.1 or newer.
A local Gradle distribution was not found, or was not properly set in the IDE.

Would you like your project to use the Gradle wrapper instead?
(The wrapper will automatically download the latest supported Gradle version).

Click 'OK' to use the Gradle wrapper, or 'Cancel' to manually set the path of a local Gradle distribution.

This error prevents me from properly import the project in android studio

how do I fix ?

Answer (score 2):

Update your gradle wrapper in `/PROJECT_ROOT/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Change the properties `distributionUrl`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip
```

And when import project use option *use gradle wrapper(recommended)*

Comment: You set 'use gradle wrapper' on import project?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is a build tool and it requires specific plugin to work.

Android Tool Team is releasing the Android plugin for Gradle.
In your `root/build.gradle` you can set the version:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0
```

You can find and set the gradle version used in your project in the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.
For example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```